# Force pandas groupby transform to return floats instead of ints

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a simple dataframe, `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'c': ['q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'w', 'w'],  
                   'd': ['z', 'z', 'z', 'o', 'o', 'o']})
```

If I use groupby apply, everything works fine:

```
df.groupby(['c', 'd']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.sum(x.a + x.b) ** .5))
            0
c d          
q o  2.828427
  z  3.464102
w o  4.690416
```

But if I use transform, the output is rounded (bad):

```
df.groupby(['c', 'd']).transform(lambda x: pd.Series(np.sum(x.a + x.b) ** .5))
   a  b
0  3  3
1  3  3
2  3  3
3  2  2
4  4  4
5  4  4
```

Trying to coerce to float from within the function doesn't seem to help:

```
df.groupby(['c', 'd']).transform(lambda x: pd.Series((float(np.sum(x.a + x.b)) ** .5), dtype='float'))
   a  b
0  3  3
1  3  3
2  3  3
3  2  2
4  4  4
5  4  4
```

Any idea what is going on or how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `transform` has the same data type as the columns in the original data frame. They use NumPy arrays to hold their values.  Make columns `a` and `b` float and it works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6.],
               'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6.],
               'c':['q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'w', 'w'],  
               'd':['z','z','z','o','o','o']})   
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 4 columns):
a    6 non-null float64
b    6 non-null float64
c    6 non-null object
d    6 non-null object
dtypes: float64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 240.0+ bytes
```

Now:

```
print(df.groupby(['c', 'd']).transform(lambda x: pd.Series(np.sum(x.a + x.b)**.5)))
```

prints:

```
         a         b
0  3.464102  3.464102
1  3.464102  3.464102
2  3.464102  3.464102
3  2.828427  2.828427
4  4.690416  4.690416
5  4.690416  4.690416
```